# How do you calculate the wife's age?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A computer engineer is twice as old as his wife was when he was as old as his wife is now. He is 24. How old is his wife?

Comment: Can the grammer be fixed? The question is worded very poorly

Comment: I'm confused as to what this is saying. Please reword this, and show context/what you have tried

Comment: It is obviously impolite to calculate a lady's age. No, I will not have any part in this.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: @VarunIyer: The wording seems clear to me. Part of the point of the problem seems to be unraveling the meaning of the question.

Comment: @RoryDaulton if it is clear to you, could you explain what exactly the question is asking?

Comment: @VarunIyer: bakula's answer implies the correct meaning. Namely: The engineer's wife has a certain age now. At some time in the past, the engineer had that certain age. At that time, his (current) wife had another age. The engineers age now is twice as large as his wife's other age. The engineer's age is now $24$. The question: What is his wife's certain age now? Is that clear?

Answer (score 3):

Let $y=$wife's current age. He was her age ($y$) exactly $(24-y)$ years ago.
At that time, she was $y - (24- y)$ years old. That is, she was $2y - 24$ years old at that time.
Today, he is (at $24$) twice that age. This means that $24 = 2\cdot (2y-24)$, so we conclude that $y = 18$.